# Pass data from textbox to crystal report without parameter promp

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have this problem in the system I am working on as a school project. I need to pass a data from a textbox straight to crystal report viewer but it always show an input parameter prompt

This is my code for it. It functions well except that the prompt would always come in.

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        With dt
            .Columns.Add("prod_name")
            .Columns.Add("price")
            .Columns.Add("quantity")
        End With


        Dim txtValue As String = TextBox7.Text & TransacTextBox.Text

        Dim myReport As New CrystalReport5

        myReport.SetParameterValue("transac_code", txtValue)


        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value, dr.Cells(3).Value)
        Next


        Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

        rptDoc = New CrystalReport5

        rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)

        Form4.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc


        Form4.ShowDialog()
        Form4.Dispose()
```

Comment: You did not set a parameter value for you rptDoc

Comment: How to I do that? Can u help me?

Comment: I was able to make a way around with your tip. It's working just like how wanted it. Thank you so much!